# Measure Dedicated Server Performance

Tags: linux, performance

I run an online video streaming site and keep getting more and more dedicated servers. Our business traffic fluctuates on an annual cycle which allows us to scale back our dedicated servers during the winter, and pick up more in the summer.

The trouble I have is when I order a new server, I have noticed that some of them seem awesome and can support nearly 1000 users, and the other with the exact same specs can only do around 180-200 without suffering. We are getting dual Xeon E5-2620 processor, 16GB RAM, SSD RAID with 2 hard drives in a RAID 0.

I recently picked up a beefy server with 72GB ram, 3X SSD drives in a RAID 0 that was a "good deal" where I was going to build a awesome website on, but it seems pretty unresponsive compared with my other one with half the hardware.

What I am wondering is if you have some favorite benchmark tests I can run like hdparm to determine when I first get my server if I want to keep it, or send it back for underperformance. Both of these servers were supposed to be the same:

```
Server 1
hdparm -tT /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3:
 Timing cached reads:   27210 MB in  2.00 seconds = 13626.32 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 906 MB in  3.00 seconds = 301.71 MB/sec


Server 2
hdparm -tT /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3:
Timing cached reads:   13124 MB in  2.00 seconds = 6567.52 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 678 MB in  3.01 seconds = 225.53 MB/sec
```

Comment: rather than using hdparm I would suggest doing tests with fio; http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442451-inspecting-disk-io-performance-with-fio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like smartmontools to check the drives don't have any errors being reported which could cause reduced performance. The brand/model of the SSD can also make a huge difference. Maybe one server has an enterprise SSD, while the other is a desktop version.

Debian:

```
apt-get install smartmontools
```

Redhat:

```
yum install smartmontools
```

Then check your drive using

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

I also assume you've run the test multiple times, without any significant load on the server/drive?